# Is there an EF equivalent of Hibernate's indexed collection feature?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list, ef-code-first, navigation-properties

As specified in section 11.1.38 of the JPA 2.0 spec, JPA supports mapping the "to-many" side of a relationship as a Java `List` using the `OrderBy` annotation.  The spec gives two examples:

```java
// Example 1
@Entity public class Course {
    //...
    @ManyToMany
    @OrderBy("lastname ASC")
    public List<Student> getStudents() {...};
    //...
}

// Example 2
@Entity public class Student {
    //...
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="students")
    @OrderBy // PK is assumed
    public List<Course> getCourses() {...};
    //...
}
```

In Hibernate, this feature is called [indexed collection mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-indexed).

NHibernate appears to also support mapping a collection as an `IList<T>`:
http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 and would like to use `IList` as the type of a navigation property (where the elements of the list are ordered by a certain property), but I have only seen `ICollection` used as the type.

I have looked at [Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738520(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Relationships and Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) on MSDN, but these two pages provide a high-level overview of the navigation property concept.

Does Entity Framework support mapping indexed collections?

Comment: You can use `IList` for navigation properties for many to many relationships in EF, but they are not ordered.